# How to type a helper function that accepts only certain properties based on what value was specified for previous property?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build an alias-builder helper function that would help me know which properties are accepted for a specific, selected table.

Suppose the following:

```
interface ITableBase {
  id: number;
}

interface ITableA extends ITableBase {
  name: string;
}

interface ITableB extends ITableBase {
  hobbies: string[];
}

const tableAliases = {
  ENVIRONMENT_A: {
    TABLE_A: (specificty: number) => `__table_a__${specificty}__`,
    TABLE_B: (specificty: number) => `__table_b__${specificty}__`,
  }
}

const generateTableAlias = ({
  alias,
  property,
  specificty = 1
}: {
  alias: keyof typeof tableAliases.ENVIRONMENT_A,
  property: string;
  specificty?: number
}) => `${tableAliases.ENVIRONMENT_A[alias](specificty)}.${property}`
```

I would like typescript to recognize the following:

```
const tableAlias1 = generateTableAlias({ alias: 'TABLE_A', property: 'hobbies' }) // ts error
const tableAlias2 = generateTableAlias({ alias: 'TABLE_A', property: 'name' }) // no error
```

Is it possible to accomplish something like this?

Comment: You can create a type alias that maps each table alias to its corresponding table interface and the allowed properties for each property of the interface. Then, you can use a conditional type to restrict the property argument to only the allowed properties based on the alias argument.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w255bW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz This is very close! It is [failing here](https://tsplay.dev/m3xxyW), though

Comment: Either way, please submit this as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: I don't see a source/target requirement in your question; is that something you want dealt with? If so then you need it to be generic for each one like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOLLRN), not smush them both together with one generic.  Anyway I'm not going to talk about that because it's not in the question.  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Oh, nice use of `satisfies`! Be aware that it's only available in TypeScript 4.9 though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you'll need to tell the compiler about the relationship between the strings `"TABLE_A"`/`"TABLE_B"` and the types `ITableA`/`ITableB`.  The easiest way to do that is with a helper [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces), since object types naturally encapsulate such relationships as key-value pairs:

```
interface TableMapping {
    TABLE_A: ITableA;
    TABLE_B: ITableB;
}
```

---

As an aside, once you have this type you can use it to verify that `tableAliases` has all the properties you expect:

```
const tableAliases = {
    ENVIRONMENT_A: {
        TABLE_A: (specificty: number) => `__table_a__${specificty}__`,
        TABLE_B: (specificty: number) => `__table_b__${specificty}__`,
    }
} satisfies {
    ENVIRONMENT_A: Record<keyof TableMapping, (spty: number) => string>
}
```

where I'm using [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to check the type without widening it.  If you are missing a property in `tableAliases`, the discrepancy should result in an error (so if you add things to `TableMapping` you should get a warning to remind you to make analogous changes to `tableAliases`). This isn't strictly necessary, but it is probably helpful.

---

Anyway, now you want `generateTableAlias` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` of the `alias` property of the input, as follows:

```
const generateTableAlias = <K extends keyof TableMapping>({
    alias,
    property,
    specificty = 1
}: {
    alias: K,
    property: string & keyof TableMapping[K];
    specificty?: number
}) => `${tableAliases.ENVIRONMENT_A[alias](specificty)}.${property}`
```

The compiler will use the `alias` property of the argument to infer `K`.  Once this happens, the compiler will then check that the `property` property is of type `string & keyof TableMapping[K]`, meaning it must be a `string`, and it must also be one of the keys of `TableMapping[K]`, an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) corresponding to the property type of `TableMapping` whose key is of type `K`.  So if `K` is `"TABLE_A"`, then `property` must be of type `string & keyof TableMapping["TABLE_A"]`, which is `string & keyof ITableA`, which is `string & ("id" | "name")`, which is just `"id" | "name"`.  And the analogous check is done for `"TABLE_B"`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const tableAlias1 = generateTableAlias(
   { alias: 'TABLE_A', property: 'hobbies' } // error!
// ------------------> ~~~~~~~~
// Type '"hobbies"' is not assignable to type '"name" | "id"'.
);

const tableAlias2 = generateTableAlias(
   { alias: 'TABLE_A', property: 'name' }
); // okay
```

Looks good; this is the behavior you wanted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBU4CMA2EBCcAzigN4BQyVywAJgFzIgCuAtltANzkC+55oSLEQoM2PAEFkEAB6QQtImky4CxMpWog4rCIyJgooAObc+A8NHhJl4gtLkQFSsasIlkFasgAWAeywsYAgifUMTAG0AXTN+cgB6eOQATz9mJggIWmQwPxyIHBwcnxQEP1YAB2A8KGRsNLBi4CUoArgwYD8QIh9gCoshaxQVPABZOAqqkGNPTSp0CXwAGQBRAH0JRldJbm8F5fX8LZGCWPIy7sawOwkcYHUlAF5Z7xWAOQA1VAAlAHk30bvdAbRhebzUfarEHIAAURAqEAQwBgwAQYGSjBY7GgAEpkI8AHzIAAGazW11UazgZIAJKR4Yjkaj0TwycSADRzcGQw6MOEIpEotEYphsDhQPGEklkil4NZYWn0gVM4WstYcrl8HjIIjtZookIvajvL5-AFA6HfRF+KC0AA8AGsIKkYMgTuNJiZ2bD4ejMWLcfiiQYjNMCbx+BcDMhjE5oO0ICdbvcnsg7QBpBzyRTIJ0ut12D1TYwEmFgqhwO7ETneCpQPwIqDomvUBmC5nJfHIACMvFBXMrKcY6ZbVDrDegfp14WmyAAZLnnX5Xe6JsWIumYly2yr0QB+f3YqC8SVE4l02UQZMPAB0Jp+-0Bb2BEgig+IUX5jKF6JxPBvdLjo2LLEpGXTRpe15EN2XaxiA8aQEmVZEGWdTIYwADkPIbBh3pAZOIoYf4gTBEQGHIDweKJDkSjQPWx7UegyQIsgGEAETEUEIRseRzRMH4jTEEQwDGNoqg5Hk6Isex2i6GxyAAD7IGxdA8TeMIAEwAMwaRpOLnOBVw3MhGmwXGUAJkhKaoe+oSsdhEi4cg+FNoRskQORlHINRIB5HRNpAA)